# React hover over button cause another button to be hovered over

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hover

Sorry about the title, I couldn't think of how to word this succinctly.

So I've got a group of buttons as part of a React component:

```
export default class AdvancedSearch extends React.Component{

    hover(){

    }

    render(){
            return(
                <div className="btn-group">
                    <button id="star1" type="button" className="btn btn-default" onMouseEnter={() => this.hover()}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></button>
                    <button id="star2" type="button" className="btn btn-default" onMouseEnter={() => this.hover()}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></button>
                    <button id="star3" type="button" className="btn btn-default" onMouseEnter={() => this.hover()}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></button>
                    <button id="star4" type="button" className="btn btn-default" onMouseEnter={() => this.hover()}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></button>
                    <button id="star5" type="button" className="btn btn-default" onMouseEnter={() => this.hover()}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></button>
                </div>
            );
    }
```

What I want to happen is when I hover over a button, all buttons to the left of it have their background change as if they were being hovered over as well. I have no idea what I can put inside the hover function to make this happen, or if that is even the best way to go about doing this. What would be the best way to get this effect? Also, I will want to be able to do the same thing when a button is clicked on as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the component state and CSS classes.

```
export default class AdvancedSearch extends React.Component{

getInitialState() {
    return {
        hoveredIndex: -1
    };
}

hover(index){
    this.setState({
        hoveredIndex: index
    });
}

leave() {
    this.setState({
        hoveredIndex: -1
    });
}

render(){
    var buttons = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let className = 'glyphicon';
        if (i <= this.state.hoveredIndex)
            className += ' glyphicon-star';
        else
            className += ' glyphicon-star-empty';

        buttons.push(
            <button id={'star'+(i+1)} type="button" className="btn btn-default" onMouseEnter={this.hover.bind(this, i)} onMouseLeave={this.leave}><span className={className}></span></button>
        );
    }

        return(
            <div className="btn-group">
                {buttons}
            </div>
        );
}
```

You should be able to inspire yourself from that for the click events or any other form of transformation ;)